# Tensorflow Model Add issue for text generation

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm following along this model, [Text Generators](https://github.com/pranjal52/text_generators/blob/master/baseline_model.ipynb), and I'm stuck. This is my first tensorflow attempt so I'm not sure what the issue is but, since it worked in the tutorial and it isn't working for me, seems like there was maybe an update. Has model.add's format changed? I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this issue since I'm so new to the library.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(400, input_shape=(X_modified.shape[1], X_modified.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(400))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(Y_modified.shape[1], activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
```

Throws the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-5a0fde131e03> in <module>()
  1 model = Sequential()
----> 2 model.add(LSTM(400, input_shape=(X_modified.shape[1], X_modified.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
  3 model.add(Dropout(0.2))
  4 model.add(LSTM(400))
  5 model.add(Dropout(0.2))

~/anaconda/envs/dataweekends/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py in add(self, layer)
162                     # and create the node connecting the current layer
163                     # to the input layer we just created.
--> 164                     layer(x)
165                     set_inputs = True
166                 else:

~/anaconda/envs/dataweekends/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/layers/recurrent.py in __call__(self, inputs, initial_state, constants, **kwargs)
498 
499         if initial_state is None and constants is None:
--> 500             return super(RNN, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
501 
502         # If any of `initial_state` or `constants` are specified and are Keras

~/anaconda/envs/dataweekends/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
429                                          'You can build it manually via: '
430                                          '`layer.build(batch_input_shape)`')
--> 431                 self.build(unpack_singleton(input_shapes))
432                 self.built = True
433 

~/anaconda/envs/dataweekends/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/layers/recurrent.py in build(self, input_shape)
459                 self.cell.build([step_input_shape] + constants_shape)
460             else:
--> 461                 self.cell.build(step_input_shape)
462 
463         # set or validate state_spec

~/anaconda/envs/dataweekends/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/layers/recurrent.py in build(self, input_shape)
   1819                                         initializer=bias_initializer,
   1820                                         regularizer=self.bias_regularizer,
-> 1821                                         constraint=self.bias_constraint)
   1822         else:
   1823             self.bias = None

~/anaconda/envs/dataweekends/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
 89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name +
 90                               '` call to the Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
 92         wrapper._original_function = func
 93         return wrapper

~/anaconda/envs/dataweekends/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in add_weight(self, name, shape, dtype, initializer, regularizer, trainable, constraint)
247         if dtype is None:
248             dtype = K.floatx()
--> 249         weight = K.variable(initializer(shape),
250                             dtype=dtype,
251                             name=name,

~/anaconda/envs/dataweekends/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/layers/recurrent.py in bias_initializer(_, *args, **kwargs)
   1811                         self.bias_initializer((self.units,), *args, **kwargs),
   1812                         initializers.Ones()((self.units,), *args, **kwargs),
-> 1813                         self.bias_initializer((self.units * 2,), *args, **kwargs),
   1814                     ])
   1815             else:

~/anaconda/envs/dataweekends/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in concatenate(tensors, axis)
   1932         return tf.sparse_concat(axis, tensors)
   1933     else:
-> 1934         return tf.concat([to_dense(x) for x in tensors], axis)
   1935 
   1936 

~/anaconda/envs/dataweekends/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py in concat(concat_dim, values, name)
   1073       ops.convert_to_tensor(concat_dim,
   1074                             name="concat_dim",
-> 1075                             dtype=dtypes.int32).get_shape(
   1076                             ).assert_is_compatible_with(tensor_shape.scalar())
   1077       return identity(values[0], name=scope)

~/anaconda/envs/dataweekends/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype)
667 
668         if ret is None:
--> 669           ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
    670 
    671         if ret is NotImplemented:

~/anaconda/envs/dataweekends/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_tensor_conversion_function(v, dtype, name, as_ref)
    174                                          as_ref=False):
    175   _ = as_ref
    --> 176   return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    177 
    178 

~/anaconda/envs/dataweekends/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape)
    163   tensor_value = attr_value_pb2.AttrValue()
    164   tensor_value.tensor.CopyFrom(
--> 165       tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
    166   dtype_value =     attr_value_pb2.AttrValue(type=tensor_value.tensor.dtype)
    167   const_tensor = g.create_op(

~/anaconda/envs/dataweekends/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    365       nparray = np.empty(shape, dtype=np_dt)
    366     else:
--> 367       _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
    368       nparray = np.array(values, dtype=np_dt)
    369       # check to them.

~/anaconda/envs/dataweekends/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py in _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
    300     else:
    301       raise TypeError("Expected %s, got %s of type '%s' instead." %
    --> 302                       (dtype.name, repr(mismatch), type(mismatch).__name__))
    303 
    304 

TypeError: Expected int32, got list containing Tensors of type '_Message' instead.
```

I've tried updating tensorflow in the Anaconda virtual env bash but it says it's already upgraded:

```
mysite heathercohen$ pip install tensorflow --upgrade
Requirement already up-to-date: tensorflow in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six>=1.10.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: gast>=0.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: absl-py>=0.1.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: setuptools<=39.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow) (39.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: grpcio>=1.8.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: protobuf>=3.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow) (3.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: astor>=0.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy<=1.14.5,>=1.13.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.14.5)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: wheel>=0.26 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.31.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: termcolor>=1.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: tensorboard<1.11.0,>=1.10.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: markdown>=2.6.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorboard<1.11.0,>=1.10.0->tensorflow) (2.6.11)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: werkzeug>=0.11.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorboard<1.11.0,>=1.10.0->tensorflow) (0.14.1)
```

When I call the library in the jupyter notebook that's in the same env though, I get

```
TensorFlow version: 0.12.0
```

I've also tried to upgrade it directly from the jupyter notebook:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install --upgrade tensorflow


Requirement already up-to-date: tensorflow in /Users/heathercohen/anaconda/envs/dataweekends/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: protobuf==3.1.0 in /Users/heathercohen/anaconda/envs/dataweekends/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorflow) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: wheel>=0.26 in /Users/heathercohen/anaconda/envs/dataweekends/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.31.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy>=1.11.0 in /Users/heathercohen/anaconda/envs/dataweekends/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six>=1.10.0 in /Users/heathercohen/anaconda/envs/dataweekends/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: setuptools in /Users/heathercohen/anaconda/envs/dataweekends/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from protobuf==3.1.0->tensorflow) (40.0.0)
```

Can anyone confirm if the issue is indeed the version of tensorflow and, if so, how I can update it when the above attempts failed?

UPDATE: I managed to get tensorflow 1.4.1 installed via pip3 and now I get the following error after the above bit of code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-3e683776aec4> in <module>()
  1 model = Sequential()
----> 2 model.add(LSTM(400, input_shape=(X_modified.shape[1], X_modified.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
  3 model.add(Dropout(0.2))
  4 model.add(LSTM(400))
  5 model.add(Dropout(0.2))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py in add(self, layer)
162                     # and create the node connecting the current layer
163                     # to the input layer we just created.
--> 164                     layer(x)
165                     set_inputs = True
166                 else:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/recurrent.py in __call__(self, inputs, initial_state, constants, **kwargs)
498 
499         if initial_state is None and constants is None:
--> 500             return super(RNN, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
501 
502         # If any of `initial_state` or `constants` are specified and are Keras

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
455             # Actually call the layer,
456             # collecting output(s), mask(s), and shape(s).
--> 457             output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
458             output_mask = self.compute_mask(inputs, previous_mask)
459 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/recurrent.py in call(self, inputs, mask, training, initial_state)
   2110                                       mask=mask,
   2111                                       training=training,
-> 2112                                       initial_state=initial_state)
   2113 
   2114     @property

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/recurrent.py in call(self, inputs, mask, training, initial_state, constants)
607                                              mask=mask,
608                                              unroll=self.unroll,
--> 609                                              input_length=timesteps)
610         if self.stateful:
611             updates = []

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in rnn(step_function, inputs, initial_states, go_backwards, mask, constants, unroll, input_length)
   2960             parallel_iterations=32,
   2961             swap_memory=True,
-> 2962             maximum_iterations=input_length)
   2963         last_time = final_outputs[0]
   2964         output_ta = final_outputs[1]

TypeError: while_loop() got an unexpected keyword argument 'maximum_iterations'
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by uninstalling keras and reinstalling while forcing the version that is necessary

```
pip3 uninstall keras
pip3 install keras==2.1.2
```